# How to disable query from effecting the entire html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load an html page into anothter html page . I have used the reference : 
[Embedding Html page inside another Html page without using iFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590981/embedding-html-page-inside-another-html-page-without-using-iframes)

I have a html page say(page1.html) . Now I want to load the contents of another page(page2.html) into the div element of page1.html . However ,I am able to do it in a basic form using jquery . 
Now, my problem is that , all the external styles (javascript , css ) will be applied to the whole of page1.html document rather than the  div element itself . Is there any way to apply all the styling only to the selected div element of page1.html rather than the entire page1.html ?

Also , it takes a while (1-3sec) to load the page after its inside page is loaded .Can this delay be minimized ?

The code is as shown below :

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="./jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var current_page=1;

  function prev()
  {
    //pass the prev pageno
    if(current_page-1>0)
    {   
    location.href = "http://192.168.12.77:8000" + "?page="+(current_page-1);
    }
    else
    {   
    alert('You are viewing the first page !');
    }
  }
  function next()
  {
    //pass the next page no
    if((current_page+1)>=4)
    {
        alert("You are viewing the last page !");
    }
    else    
    {
    location.href = "http://192.168.12.77:8000" + "?page="+(current_page+1);
        alert(current_page+1);
    }   

  }
  </script>
  <body>
  <table>
  <tr>

  <td width ="150">
  <button id="prev" onclick="prev()">Previous</button>
  </td>

  <td height="800" width ="1000">
  <div id="dummy_body">

  </div>
  </td>

  <td width ="150" style="padding:00px 20px">
  <button id="prev"  onclick="next()" >Next</button>
  </td>

  </tr>
  </table>
  <script> $(function() {      
   $("#dummy_body").load(".test1.html");
  });
  </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: you can wrap your inner page into div element set class or id and add logic to elements at this div.

Comment: what prevents you from changing the js so it will only apply to classes/id's of the partial you load? what kind of negative effect you have when you load your html page?

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak  could you be more specific on "add logic to elements at this div "

Comment: @gulty : its not the js of page2.html that I am worried about . .Its actually the css .. Say , page2.html has background color as black , then my entire page1.html also becomes black . Whereas I want only the div tag to have the black background .

Comment: I mean change you js for inner page to something like this `$("div.inner-page").find("input#test).on("click")` and so on

Comment: css is very powerfull and let you make you different kind of chainings

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are two ways to solve your problem.

- If you are using HTML5, you can use the scoped attribute for style blocks.

  ```
  <div>
  <style scoped>
      ...
  </style>
  </div>
  ```

  The css in above style block will not affect anything outside the enclosing div.
  In your case you might have to preprocess the page to be loaded by making all style    scoped.
  For more, refer to [Saving the Day with Scoped CSS](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/)
- In your case best approach would be to use an iframe. Once you load the page inside an iframe, its css will not affect the rest of the page.

  ```
  var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
  var html = '<p>Hello World!</p>';
  iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
  iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . And i am completely aware about iframe in HTML5. The thing is that I don't want to use IFrame due to some reason .So ,i was working on a roundabout for that  .  That's the reason i've mentioned a link in my question . And , now regard to style scoped ,  thanks for that . .Will definetely look into it .